# Joining 2 Armatures and keeping the weights

Tags: modeling, rigging, armature, weight-painting

I have two separate Armatures that I want to join together. I have no problem combining the meshes, but the problem is the bones/rigs. When you do the Object mode > join, I lose all of my weight paint on one of my armatures. Is there any way I can join two separate armatures and keep all the weight paint. I turn my models into XPS and use XNA Lara to view them, but XNAlara cannot use both armatures at once.

Answer (score 7):

Weight is a property of a Vertex Group, it's not about rigs but about meshes.

Every single vertex will be moved by a bone if the bone has exactly the same name of a vertex group to which the vertex has some weight, and the whole mesh must have an armature modifier pointing to the rig.

When you merge two meshes, all vertices retain their weights, but if some vertex groups have the same name, some will be renamed with the ".001" suffix, and they will stop to be influenced by the bone.

The same can happen if you join two armatures which have some bones with the same name.

So you have to check the right correspondence between bone names and vertex groups names, and eventually rename some bones to avoid overlapping (if you rename a bone in a working model, its vertex group will be automatically renamed in the correct way).

If every datablock has different names, everything will work well after joining.

Don't forget to apply rotations and scale (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>) to all objects before joining.

Answer (score 1):

(`Mesh 1`: Base mesh & armature; `mesh 2`: mesh you want to attach to bone)

Heres what you do:

1. Take `Mesh 2` and bring it under the armature of `Mesh 1`.
2. Now inside of the properties menu for `Mesh 2` find the *Modifier tab*.
3. Under *Object* set it to the correct Armature. Then under *Vertex Group* and select which bone `Mesh 2` should be attached to.

Comment: He said he had 2 armatures to join, not 2 meshes

Answer (score 0):

What did the trick for me with two already rigged meshes was the following (v 2.90):

Select the objects you want to join clicking them **under the rig** (holding shift/cmd etc.), **not the originals** you see at the bottom of the picture. Watch out though that both objects don't have the same mesh group names as this will break rigging for them.

[image]