# Linking two armatures into 1

Tags: armature, bones

[image]

2 models having their own armature,i wish to link both armatures into one ,creating a bone linking both Root bones,making it one armature.

I tried few things,it's ends up messing the mesh.

PS: No constraint.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Joining 2 Armatures and keeping the weights](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/129679/joining-2-armatures-and-keeping-the-weights)

Comment: by curiosity, why don't you keep the two objects and armatures separate?

Answer (score 0):

Select bones of first armature then hold shift and select bones of the second armature and at the end then press ctrl + j. This must be done in object mode. I think this will join two armatures into one.

Comment: Do not work because Mesh of model 2 will have weights of armature 1 and will be moved away from it's original armature

Comment: @Mai Sasaki then you need to rename bones so that there aren't any name collisions, and you need to apply location on the armature and its children (the mesh.)