# Is it possible to join separate armatures after weight painting?

Tags: modeling, rigging, armature, weight-painting

I have weight painted my bones exactly how I want them but they are separate. I now want to join them while keeping their respective weights. The problem I face is that when I join the leg armature to the torso armature, the leg object moves to the torso while the armature maintains it's correct position. I have tried ctrl+a to apply rotation/scale/position but that doesn't seem to work. I have also made sure my armatures and their bones are named differently.

You can see the before and after joining images attached. Is there a way I can join these armatures while retaining the positions and weight for each separate object?

[image][image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Joining 2 Armatures and keeping the weights](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/129679/joining-2-armatures-and-keeping-the-weights)

Comment: I checked that question and no solution worked for me

Comment: You also need to apply transforms to armatures/meshes first. Your armatures have different origins which is a bad sign.

Comment: Now I have applied the transforms to everything and it works. The armatures combine while everyting maintains position, however the leg now doesn't respond to the armature