# How can I match 2 different armatures

Tags: animation, pose-mode

I am a real beginner, this is like the 3rd time I am using Blender.

I exported the csgo files into the software but I can't animate them because when I enter the pose mode I can only move the character and the gloves keep standing still (image 3).

So, I was wondering if there is a way I can move the gloves and the character at the same time and how I could do that, maybe if I could match both rigs. Any kind of help would be good.

[image: gloves]
[image: character]
[image: character and gloves]

Comment: Hello and welcome! You can upload and add images directly to your question so readers get immediately an overview and don't have to click back and forth between the text and the images. This saves time.

Comment: You could try to change the parent of the gloves to the parent of the character and change the used armature ("skeleton") in the Armature modifier of the gloves. -Or- just select the gloves object and the character's armature (must be selected last) and parent them *With Empty Groups* (Ctrl+P). This does the same in one operation. But it's just a guess, I have no clue if this will work for your objects.

Comment: @Blunder: if he really uses Blender for the 3rd time...he won't understand what you are writing ;) and he shouldn't rig at all ;) He should just watch beginner tutorials and try to follow them...just my 5 cent. But i admire your patience ;)

Comment: Yes, you're right. This thought also crossed my mind as I was writing the comment. But Apolo managed to import fully textured models and rig them properly. He did a good job and might be an experienced Maya or 3DS Max user ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You can merge armatures and meshes. There are a few questions and answers about this if you search for "merge armature" for example this one: [Joining 2 Armatures and keeping the weights](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/129679/107598).

But I guess, there is no need for this and you can get away by just using the body's armature for the gloves. While the glove's armature seems to have no bones for the head and lower body, the body's armature looks complete. It has bones for the whole body including the hands.

**You can try (no guarantee that it will work) and use the body armature for the gloves.** This will only work when the bones for the hand have the same name in both armatures. The names of these bones must match.

To change the armature of the gloves do the following...

- in *Object* mode, select the gloves mesh object. It's called "*w_glove_ct_s..*", located under the armature.
- clear the parent relation ship by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>, *Clear Parent*. This will also automatically remove the *Armature* modifier from the modifier stack.
- still in *Object* mode, select the gloves, and press <kbd>Shift</kbd> in viewport (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> in the outliner) to select additionally the body's armature "*tm_professional_...*"
- make sure the armature is the *active* object = selected last, highlighted in an orange color
- press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>, *With Empty Groups* to parent the gloves to the body's armature
- check the modifier stack and the relationship. If you have more modifiers make sure the *Armature* modifier is in the correct position, usually first. Make sure there is only one *Armature* modifier.
- the gloves should be in the correct position now.

[image: armature in modifier stack]
<sup>Armature modifier on modifier stack (ops! Ignore the *Collision*, it should go after *Armature*)</sup>

[image: parent relationship]
<sup>Parent relationship</sup>